# Can I travel with my old passport and have the new one sent to my destination?

Tags: passports, china, biometric-passports, afghan-citizens

I recently applied for a new passport while I still have my previous one. I urgently want to leave the country. Can I travel with my previous passport and ask someone to deliver the new one to me?

I want to travel from Afghanistan to China and I have an Afghan passport. My previous passport is handmade or manual and the one I applied for is an electronic or computerised passport.

Comment: 1.  Which country are you in?  2.  I *think* that in the UK you have to send in your old passport when you renew.

Comment: In which country? Fiji? Ecuador? Guinea-Bissau? Details, that where the devil is, in the details...

Comment: I want to travel from afghanistan to china and i have afghan passport. My previous passport is hand made or manual and the one i applied to is electronic or computerised passport.

Comment: @MartinBonner If you have a good reason for needing two at the same time, the UK will let you get a second passport without sending in your old one.

Answer (score 2):

In most countries, as long as your new passport isn't issued, and your current passport is still valid, that's the one you can (and have to use). However different countries have different rules about pickup of a new passport. My own requires me to show up in person, *and* hand over the old one. So unless we know which country you're talking about, it's gonna be difficult to answer.

Besides, talking to the passport issuing authority is probably the best solution. *They* know.

Comment: All the countries I'm familiar with cancel the current passport when the new one is issued.

Comment: Mine (France) requires the passport holder to present the old passport in person. That passport is cancelled, and if there isn't a valid visa in it, taken away. If, on the other hand, you have a valid visa in it, you can keep the passport.